# Swift Value of protocol type 'XXX' cannot conform to 'Identifiable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Tags: swift, generics, enums, swift-protocols

I'm getting the following error:

`Value of protocol type 'MenuProtocol' cannot conform to 'Identifiable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols`

I have a main menu which some of its options have a submenu. I decided to use an `enum` for the main menu, and another `enum` for any submenus. All of the enums implement a protocol I defined, which allows me to specify the text that I'm going to show for each menu option.

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but I found it useful.

Any ideas how can I fix this error? Thanks for your help!

```
Protocol MenuProtocol {
    var submenu: [OptionProtocol] { get }
}

protocol OptionProtocol {
    var name: String { get }
}

enum MainMenu: Int, Identifiable, CaseIterable, MenuProtocol, OptionProtocol {
    case One
    case Two
    case Three
    case Four
    case Five
    
    var id: Int { rawValue }
    
    var name: String {
        switch self {
        case .One:
            return "One"
        case .Two:
            return "Two"
        case .Three:
            return "Three"
        case .Four:
            return "Four"
        case .Five:
            return "Five"
        }
    }
    
    var submenu: [OptionProtocol] {
        switch self {
        case .One:
            return SubMenu1.allCases
        case .Two:
            return SubMenu2.allCases
        default:
            return []
        }
    }
}

enum SubMenu1: Int, Identifiable, CaseIterable, OptionProtocol {
    case SubMenu1_Option1
    case SubMenu1_Option2
    case SubMenu1_Option3
    case SubMenu1_Option4
    case SubMenu1_Option5
    
    var id: Int { rawValue }
    
    var name: String {
        switch self {
        case .SubMenu1_Option1:
            return "Submenu1 Option 1"
        case .SubMenu1_Option2:
            return "Submenu1 Option 2"
        case .SubMenu1_Option3:
            return "Submenu1 Option 3"
        case .SubMenu1_Option4:
            return "Submenu1 Option 4"
        case .SubMenu1_Option5:
            return "Submenu1 Option 5"
        }
    }
}

enum SubMenu2: Int, Identifiable, CaseIterable, OptionProtocol {
    case SubMenu2_OptionA
    case SubMenu2_OptionB
    case SubMenu2_OptionC
    case SubMenu2_OptionD
    case SubMenu2_OptionE
    
    var id: Int { rawValue }
    
    var name: String {
        switch self {
        case .SubMenu2_OptionA:
            return "Submenu2 Option A"
        case .SubMenu2_OptionB:
            return "Submenu2 Option B"
        case .SubMenu2_OptionC:
            return "Submenu2 Option C"
        case .SubMenu2_OptionD:
            return "Submenu2 Option D"
        case .SubMenu2_OptionE:
            return "Submenu2 Option E"
        }
    }
}

struct EnumProtTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(MainMenu.allCases) { value in
                    Text("\(theName(value))")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                }
            }
            
            HStack {
                TheContentView(data: MainMenu.One.submenu) { item in
                    Text("\(item.name)")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.purple)
                }
            }
            
            HStack {
                TheContentView(data: MainMenu.Two.submenu) { item in
                    Text("\(item.name)")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.purple)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TheContentView<Data: RandomAccessCollection, ElementView: View>: View where Data.Element: Identifiable, Data.Element: Hashable {
    
    var data: Data
    var itemView: (Data.Element) -> ElementView
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(data) { item in
            itemView(item)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.purple)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ForEach` expects an `Identifiable` type, that’s why your Menu*-types conform to `Identifiable`. But what is passed to `ForEach` is a `MenuProtocol` that doesn‘t conform to `Identifiable`.

In general, when upcasting an object (e.g. `MainMenu`) to a base-class or protocol (in your case `MenuProtocol`), the compiler is only able to access the properties/functions that are provided by that protocol. This limitation is due the fact that you may also pass other objects that conform to the protocol but miss all the other properties like the `id` In your case.

In your example I don’t see a reason for having a protocol-oriented implementation for the Menu, because you don‘t use `MainMenu` and `SubMenu1` in a polymorphism way. My suggestion when it comes to protocols and generics and inheritance: try to keep it as simple as possible without any of those features and add those if you cannot solve your problem without.

Good WWDC video and podcast about protocol-oriented programming
https://developer.apple.com/wwdc15/408
https://www.swiftbysundell.com/podcast/71/

Comment: Hi Nino, I have updated my code trying to show why I need such implementation of enums. I haven't find a better way to do it. I don't see how can I solve this without the current implementation.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend protocol inheritance.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33154747)